# Laravel Sanctum always returns 401 unauthorized in Production

Tags: vuejs3, vite, laravel-9, laravel-sanctum, nuxt3

I am using this starter [vitesse-nuxt3](https://github.com/antfu/vitesse-nuxt3) with backend [Laravel 9 Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum) setup. I also use [nuxt-sanctum-auth](https://github.com/dystcz/nuxt-sanctum-auth) package and it is totally working fine in my local development.

However, in production, I'm having trouble with this error `401 unauthorized`. I can confirm that login was successful. But seems having trouble with the middleware `auth:sanctum`.

**What I've done so far as suggested by others:**

1. .env

   ```
   SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS="mydomain.com"
   SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
   SESSION_DOMAIN=.mydomain.com
   ```
2. cors.php

   ```
   'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],
   'supports_credentials' => true,
   ```
3. I tried using `Postman` and it works (so maybe it's between frontend and backend issues)

**BACKEND LOGIN AUTH:**

```
  public function login(Request $request) {
    if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])){ 
      // I can confirm this line after successful login
      $user = Auth::user();
      $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')->plainTextToken;
      $success['name'] =  $user->name;

      return $this->sendResponse($success, 'User login successfully.');
    }
    else{ 
      // My frontend app recognized this after attempting to use wrong credentials
      return $this->sendError('Failed.', ['error'=>'Login failed']);
    } 
  }
```

**FRONTEND AUTH LOGIN:**

```
  try {
    await $sanctumAuth.login({
      email: form.value.username,
      password: form.value.password
    })
    loading.value = false

    console.log("logged in!!!") // I can access this line after successful login

  } catch (e) {
    // your error handling
    // errors.value = e.errors
    console.log(e) // I can see this log after attempting to use wrong credentials

    alert.value.active = true
    alert.value.message = e.data.error
    alert.value.type = "danger"
    useraccount.toggleTrigger(true)

    setTimeout(() => {
      useraccount.toggleTrigger(false)
    }, 10000);

    loading.value = false
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

*Additional details:*

I am also working with subdomains using `https`:

1. **Frontend (vitesse):** `https://fe.mydomain.com`
2. **Backend (Laravel 9):** `https://be.mydomain.com`

I've read about sanctum having issues with subdomain, I'm not sure if it's true but here's the [link](https://github.com/laravel/sanctum/issues/156).

Answer (score 1):

Hi are you sending your cookies with each subsequent request from the frontend? The `.env` files look typical. Instead of using wildcards sometimes use the explicit subdomains then once that works use the wildcard (I prefer to be explicit unless you have literally dynamic subdomains).

You're 100% sure you're applying the `auth:sanctum` middleware to the route that requires auth and your `\Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class` is applied to your Api routes (or any route definition not web)?

Try to reduce it to as simple as a setup as possible to find the buggy config before layering on any complexity.

I would also suggest using session based on something like database or redis driver if possible, your cookie may not be sending properly if laravel doesn't know you want it to be available on multiple subdomains or a wildcard.

Comment: Yes. I also tried it but with no luck. I can also confirm that token is always present in the database whenever I log in. I honestly tried everything on google before posting it here.

Comment: So you're using the personal access token and not the stateful cookie based auth login correct? To me it sounds like you don't need to use a token, just let laravel get your session for Api routes or normally stateless routes with the Sanctum Stateful middleware.

Is your SPA first party? Seems like it to me since its on a subdomain you control.

If you use the token you need to set it as the value of the Authorization header

Per Docs:
You should not use API tokens to authenticate your own first-party SPA. Instead, use Sanctum's built-in SPA authentication features.

Answer (score 1):

I've had issues with that as well with an app using subdomains.

Try setting the `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS` env var to `fe.mydomain.com`.

Sidenote:
The `"` in .envs are not required.